# Control android app using presentation trigger

Tags: java, android

I have a client want me to build a tablet mobile app that can be controlled by presentation trigger device

Like this : 
 https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/Amerteer-Laser-Pointer-Pen-PowerPoint-Presentation-Remote-Control-Clickers-1mw/3013893718

Can anyone tell me if that is possible and if possible, is there any sdk that allow me to do that

The device is connected to tablet using thus cabel

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are USB triggers; how would they connect to a tablet? The solution below would work on a PC, but there may be an equivalent solution for the device you are using which is similar to the following:

Many of these triggers work by simply sending a keyboard input. All you would have to do is detect keypresses (how you do this will depend on what you are creating this application on) and handle them accordingly. I believe the up/down keys on most presentation triggers actually send the pageup/pagedown key rather than the up/down arrows, so that may be something to look out for.

EDIT:

Try adding this method into your Activity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == 123) { //TODO find the correct key code
        // your code here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can find out the key codes by adding some logging to that method and pressing the buttons on the clicker while it is connected to the tablet.

Comment: I am seeing a micro USB connection, so is it correct to assume this will be for Android tabets?

Comment: Yes the app will be for android tablet

Comment: Ok, this should hopefully be possible then as long as the device sends signals which Android can handle. Android does support external keyboard inputs, see: https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices . You may get this to work as long as the operating system can treat the signals sent by the device as keypresses. If this is the case, then you can use the same method which I explained above.

Comment: do you know any tutorial or example that may help me implement it, I have searched but I only find handling for key events and key actions on edittext

Comment: ok I will try it and get back to you, and Thanks a lot for your help